# Ajax deep linking without hash sign

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Is it possible to do Ajax Deep Linking without hash sign (#) in the url. Knowing that my urls don't point to any controller/action on the server.

For example How does Stackoverflow or Soundcloud to manage  the url?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Downvoters please leave a comment so I can update my question

Comment: I can't speak for the downvoter (just one as of this writing), but one person voted to close as "unclear what you're asking", and two people voted to close as "too broad". Not my area of expertise, so I don't have an opinion, I'm just passing on the information as an FYI, since you requested feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a query string, but the `#` is better since it doesn't give the appearance of different resources on the server.

Stackoverflow doesn't use Ajax (afaik) to load pages (if they did, they would use the technique below). I've no idea what Soundcloud does as I don't use them.

Twitter and Github use the [history api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) (`pushState` and friends) but populate the initial page load server side (i.e. they don't load a default page and then overwrite it using JavaScript).

Doing it server side in this fashion is the preferred approach. It loads the requested content faster (and without the *flash of homepage problem)*, continues to work if [JavaScript fails](http://digital.cabinetoffice.gov.uk/2013/10/21/how-many-people-are-missing-out-on-javascript-enhancement/), and is search engine friendly.

Comment: I have tried to use the History api with pushstate and it is working for browser back button or bookmarking. But when I refresh the page I get a 404 error . How can I handle the refresh button..?

Comment: As I said - you have to populate the page server side.

Comment: Ok Im not sure I undersand 100% your response but I understand I have to provide page server side. Thank you